# Some images load, some after few refreshes

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I am loading images srcs as an array of strings from supabase to display them on my webpage. Sometimes some images load, sometimes none of them loads. After some refreshing of the webpage I get them loaded. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. When I copy link into another window, it loads the picture.
It shows spinner for 1 second, then it aborts loading and throw an error in q-img.
Background: I'm doing quasar app, running it through local host.
Thank you.

I listed links in

tag. It works, but it doesnt wait for image to load.

CODE:

```
<template>
  <!-- slide gallery -->
  <div
    class="q-mx-auto"
    style="width: 600px"
  >
    <q-carousel
      v-model="slide"
      swipeable
      animated
      arrows
      thumbnails
      infinite
      :fullscreen="fullscreen"
    >
      <q-carousel-slide
        v-for="doc in props.project.photos"
        :key="doc"
        :name="doc"
        :img-src="doc"
      />

      <template #control>
        <q-carousel-control position="bottom-right">
          <q-btn
            color="white"
            icon="fullscreen"
            text-color="black"

            @click="fullscreen=!fullscreen"
          />
        </q-carousel-control>
      </template>
    </q-carousel>
    <div class="text-h5 text-left q-py-md">
      <p>{{ props.project.projectDescription }}</p>
      <p v-if="props.project.countries">
        Participants from: <br> {{ props.project.countries }}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const props = defineProps({
  project: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => {}
  }
})

const slide = ref(props.project.photos[0])
const fullscreen = ref(false)
console.log(props.project.name, 'ProjectPageComp')

</script>

<style scoped>
.q-carousel__slide {
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #C7C8CC;
}
</style>
```

Comment: "throw an error in q-img" What error?

Comment: @Yogi I added the code.
Also, when I use picsum/photos/1600 it works just fine, but when I use labnol.org embed for google drive photos, it has this problems. Could it be problem with the site?

Comment: @ceejayoz It does not show. In q-img there is event (at)error, so I put there console.log('error') and it shows in console, it loads for like 0,5 seconds and then abort. 
Could it be something with labnol.org? Because I with picsum.photos/1600, it works fine. I use labnol to get photos from google drive.

Comment: `console.log('error')` will just log the word "error". Log the actual details of the error. If you're doing `catch(error)`, you want `console.log(error)` - note the lack of apostrophes.